# Trying to pass string to javascript from Rails view gives "missing ; before statement" error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Trying to pass string data produces the desired result in HTML but not sure why I am getting "missing ; before statement" error.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.context_user_email = <%= @context_user_email %>;
<% end %>
```

gives...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

        window.context_user_email = some@example.com;

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add quotes it will become a string variable, otherwise it is just a syntax error:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.context_user_email = "<%= @context_user_email %>";
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`some@example.com` should be quoted like

```
"some@example.com" 

<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.context_user_email = "<%= @context_user_email %>";
<% end %>
```

since it must be read as a string-value